# enter command output to variable in batch

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I need to check in my batch script what `python --version` response is.

For that, I want to enter to a variable the output of the `python --version` commands :

```
set /u cmd=python --version
%cmd%
```

What should i do next ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop.

```
for /f "delims=!" %%i in ('python --version') do set VAR=%%i
echo %VAR%
```

I changed %cmd% to %VAR% as it is a bad idea to `set` variable names that resemble system commands such as `cmd` which is in fact `cmd.exe`